# How can I sort the quantity to highest to lowest in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to sort the medicine quantity into highest to lowest. The problem is the lowest quantity came first before the highest quantity. How can I sort the quantity from highest to lowest? Here's my query

```
  SELECT tbl_transaction_details.supplier_medicine_id, tbl_supplier_medicine.medicine_name
        AS 
            MedicineName, tbl_category.description 
        AS 
            Category, tbl_unit_category.unit 
        AS 
            Unit_Category, SUM(tbl_transaction_details.quantity)
        AS
            Quantity 
        FROM 
            tbl_transaction_details 
        INNER JOIN 
            tbl_supplier_medicine ON tbl_transaction_details.supplier_medicine_id = tbl_supplier_medicine.supplier_medicine_id
        INNER JOIN 
            tbl_category ON tbl_category.category_id = tbl_supplier_medicine.category_id 
        INNER JOIN 
            tbl_unit_category ON tbl_unit_category.unit_category_id = tbl_supplier_medicine.unit_category_id
        INNER JOIN 
            tbl_transaction ON tbl_transaction.transaction_id = tbl_transaction_details.transaction_id
        INNER JOIN 
            tbl_barangay ON tbl_barangay.barangay_id = tbl_transaction.barangay_id 
        WHERE 
            tbl_barangay.barangay_id = 1
        AND
            (tbl_transaction.transaction_date between  DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%M-%d-01') AND NOW()) GROUP BY tbl_transaction_details.supplier_medicine_id ASC
                        ORDER BY MAX('Quantity'), COUNT(tbl_transaction_details.supplier_medicine_id) DESC
```

Expected Result

```
MedicineName   Category Unit_Category Quantity
Paracetamol    Tablet   500mg         171
Atenolol       Tablet   100mg         24
Metoprolol     Tablet   100mg         8
Ibuprofenv     Tablet   200mg         3
```

Comment: Why do you order by `MAX('Quantity')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use `DESC` in `ORDER BY`  clause?
Just add at the end:

...    ORDER BY Quantity DESC

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
ORDER BY MAX('Quantity')
```

This is ordering by the string `'Quantity'`, not the column value.

Reference the column with no quotes:

```
ORDER BY MAX(Quantity) DESC
```

`DESC` is for the descending sort.

If you have a poorly laid out table and `Quantity` is a string, then you will want to convert to a number.  In MySQL, I think the simplest method is adding zero:

```
ORDER BY MAX(Quantity + 0)
```